# Make a single file using picture/video and audio files in android

Tags: android-intent, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder, android-mediascanner

I am developing an android app where users will see some picture or videos on screen and put voice comments over this. On finishing, user we see a new video which will have pictures or videos with his voice comments.

Cases:
1) Picture + voice comments --> New Video with original picture and voice comments.
2) Video + Voice comments --> New Video with original video and voice comments.

I have searched a lot but I did not get how can I implement this?

As per my opinion, there may be following options:
1) I store audio and picture/video files separately and then create a new video from them.
2) I create a new video at parallel in backend during the voice comments over picture/video.

but I do not know how can I implements any options ? Is there any good tutorial to do the same ?

Thanks in advance.

**No answer yet. Is my question not clear or is it not possible? Anyone please guide me. Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ffmpeg library for this. http://www.ffmpeg.org/about.html

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow... please add some more details.. as this not seems like an answer...